# How to `rebase` to avoid duplicated commits on pull request

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

1. I did a PR to a repository. Accepted and merged.
2. I `git fetch upstream` on my fork.

   [Here starts the stuff I could not understand at all]
3. I have a `commit` with a pre compiled message: *Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master'*
4. I pushed to my `remote`
5. Continue working on another feature, pushed to `remote` and create another **Pull Request** where have the (3) commits of the old PR, the *merge...* commit and the (2 last) commits that are relative to this feature.

[Here](https://github.com/pburtchaell/react-notification/pull/62) is the PR, where only the last two commits are necessary.

[image: desired commits]

As you could see, the owner propose to `rebase` but, sincerely, don't know how to solve it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

(you can change the origin/master to the branch you want to rebase on)

And then remove the lines of the unnecessary commits in the interactive mode. Then save and `git push -f`

Comment: Thanks @till, after the first command (`rebase`) it opens vim with something like _# Rebase 163554c..163554c onto 163554c (1 command(s))_.

> And then remove the lines of the necessary commits in the interactive mode.

Is something I have to do in vim?

Comment: I meant "unecessary". You keep just the last 2 lines. Then save and exit vim with `:wq`. It sould do the job.

Comment: ```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 163554c
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 163554c Apply changes for Stacked Notifications in the example
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick e5ef53e Allow Action button on Stacked Notifications
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '163554c'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

is this ok when `git status`?

Comment: If you look at your tree by doing `gitk --all` (you should install it), then you should see that you are 2 commits ahead of master and the commits are the last 2 you wanted to keep. (If you cannot use `gitk` you can do `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`

Comment: Seems that I am on HEAD and stills there the `commits` I don't want, am I wrong?

Comment: If you look [there](https://github.com/pburtchaell/react-notification/network) you see that your master starts from the 5.0.1. I think you should sync your repo with the one of pburtchaell.